# Add multiple elements to an array php

Tags: php, arrays

i try to add multiple elements to an array (in this case example1 and test1 to $allCats) but it still dont work :( can anyone explain me my mistake? or what i do wrong?

```
function getCats($Catlist, $name) {
   $regex = '('.implode('|', $Catlist).')';
   $success = preg_match_all($regex, $name, $matches);
   return $success ? $matches[0] : [];

}


function Cats($name, $wrongCatlist, $allCats, $Catlist) {

        $Cats = getCats($Catlist, $name);
        $Cats2 = array_unique ( $Cats );
        $Cats3 = '"'.implode('", "', $Cats2).'"'; 
        array_push($allCats, $Cats3);
}

        $name = "adidas example1 handschuhe test1 nike";
        $wrongCatlist = [
        ];
        global $allCats;
        $allCats = [
        ];
        $Catlist = [
        "example1",
        "test1"
        ];
        Cats($name, $wrongCatlist, $allCats, $Catlist);
        $allCats2 = ''.implode(', ', $allCats).'';
        echo $allCats2;
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP array is passed by value. Since you want the array `$allCats` to be updated the variable should get passed by reference. For that your function definition will be:

```
function Cats($name, $wrongCatlist, &$allCats, $Catlist) {

    $Cats = getCats($Catlist, $name);
    $Cats2 = array_unique ( $Cats );
    $Cats3 = '"'.implode('", "', $Cats2).'"'; 
    array_push($allCats, $Cats3);
}
```

Since pass by reference can sometimes lead to confusion, you should use return statement in function. Then the function and its call will change as below:

```
function Cats($name, $wrongCatlist, $allCats, $Catlist) {

    $Cats = getCats($Catlist, $name);
    $Cats2 = array_unique ( $Cats );
    $Cats3 = '"'.implode('", "', $Cats2).'"'; 
    array_push($allCats, $Cats3);
    return $allCats;
}

$allCats = Cats($name, $wrongCatlist, $allCats, $Catlist);
```

Comment: but that dont add $Cats3 to $allCats when i write $echo $allCats;

Comment: `$allCats` is initialised as empty array. `getCats` returns `Array ( [0] => example1 [1] => test1 )` which is then concatenated and imploded and stored in `$Cats3` as `"example1", "test1"`. This string is then pushed to `$allCats` empty array.